# 403 forbidden after installing Namecheap’s PositiveSSL

Tags: laravel, nginx, server

After installing SSL certificate with Namecheap’s PositiveSSL on my server i’m getting 403 forbidden error page. in HTTP the page does work.

I’m developing a Laravel app on a Nginx host

here’s my /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ssl.conf

```
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_bundle_guida_deltipo.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /root/azas.social.key;


server_name  azas.social;
access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
location / {

root /var/www/visibilio/visibilio/public;
index index.html;
}

}
```

And the following is nginx.conf file:

```
        ##

        # SSL Settings

        ##

        client_max_body_size 1000m;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE

        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;



        ##

        # Logging Settings

        ##



        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;







        ##

        # Virtual Host Configs

        ##



        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

}
```

this is my etc/nginx/sites-available/

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::];

    root /var/www/visibilio/visibilio/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name in-visibili.org;
    return 301 https://azas.social$request_uri;
    location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
                # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
                # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: It looks like the SSL server is trying to load index.html by default, which may or may not exist, and is missing the PHP fastcgi proxy pass as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Where do you suggest me to change te root?

Comment: Try changing the ssl.conf file to be an exact copy of the server for port 80, except change the port to 443 and add the ssl lines. Otherwise, they should be indentical; especially the `location ~ \.php$` part. Otherwise the SSL host won't be able to run PHP.

Comment: Thank you again! I did as you told me, restarted nginx but the forbidden page remains. Here's my updated ssl.conf
`server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/sites-available/nginx_bundle_guida_deltipo.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /root/azas.social.key;

    root /var/www/visibilio/visibilio;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name in-visibili.org;
    return 301 https://azas.social$request_uri;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;

`

Comment: `server_name in-visibili.org;
 return 301 https://azas.social$request_uri;
 location / {
                try_files $uri /index.php?$query_string;
        }

 error_page 404 /404.html;
 error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
 location = /50x.html {
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 }

 location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
 }

}`